# Complete multiple lines

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, insert-mode

I want to complete multiple lines at once.

For instance, in a buffer (may be hidden):

```
...
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
...
```

In the current buffer I can complete a whole line with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>.

```
using st
        ^
   CTRL-X_CTRL-L
```

How can I also complete the line along with the next lines? (they don't have to share a common prefix like in the example)

In the help `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-L` I found:

```
CTRL-X CTRL-L   After expanding a line you can additionally get the
        line next to it by typing CTRL-X CTRL-L again, unless
        a double CTRL-X is used.  Only works for loaded
        buffers.
```

which seems to be what I want, but it doesn't work. (If I enter the selection with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> the cursor remains on the same line and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> again completes the same line. If I enter the selection with <kbd>Enter</kbd> the cursor ends on the next line and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> again completes the same line (but on this new line))

Comment: it looks like it works on default settings. There is a plugin/setting of mine that breaks this. I'll edit the question / add an answer when I find out the one that breaks this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this works if you don't press `<C-Y>` to choose the selection. When you've selected the one you want using `<C-N>` and `<C-P>`, just type `<C-X><C-L>` again.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. When I press `C-X` it exits complete mode and then when I press `C-L` it inserts these 2 characters: `^L`

Comment: That sounds like you're hitting `<C-V>` instead of `<C-X>`. Do you have any Insert mappings that might be affecting this behaviour?

Comment: Actually, I just confirmed that `<C-L>` in Insert mode will insert `^L`, so there's no `<C-V>` necessary as for some other chords. Still bizarre though, this works just fine for me.

Comment: I have the YouCompleteMe plugin. Some settings I have: `:set wildmode=list:longest` `let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 0` `let g:ycm_complete_in_comments = 1` `let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 1`

Comment: I don't know anything about the plugin. Have you tested this with no plugins installed? Use `vim -u NONE -N`. If it works there, try a minimal setup where only that plugin is installed (nothing else in your vimrc). If that breaks it again, I'd be pretty confident that the plugin is the problem.

Comment: it works with `vim -u NONE -N`. So it is from a plugin or from a setting. When I'll have a little time I'll narrow it and come back with the finds. Thank you for your time.